# Adding new column of total_event

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to append virtual column in `SELECT` result with the name of `total_event` which will be total of same type of `wait_event_type`, As shown in the screenshot I want to sum 'Lock' which will be `18+2 = 20` and add that against all Lock type column.

[image]

I have a `event_stats` table with three columns wait_event_type, wait_event, event_count which holds all the data.

Comment: ever heard of group by clause?

Comment: or maybe self join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html) to do this:

```
SELECT
    wait_event_type,
    wait_event,
    event_count,
    SUM(event_count) OVER (PARTITION BY wait_event_type) AS total_event_count
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use group by clause and join
```

`select m.wait_event_type,
    m.wait_event,
    m.event_count,
    t.total_event_count from (select wait_event_type,SUM(event_count) as total_event_count 
    from my_table group by wait_event_type)t join my_table m on 
    m.wait_event_type=t.wait_event_type`